# Convolution of 2 signals, equivalences

Tags: convolution

If I have two signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and define $z(t)=x(t)∗y(t)$.

Can we say $x(t)∗y(-t)$ is equal to any of the following?

$z(−t), −z(t), −z(−t), z(t)$